# Nuget: Install target-specific content files

Tags: nuget

In Nuget, we can specify a different target for the DLLs (for instance net35, net40, winrt45 etc). Is there a way to do the same for Content files?

I am trying to have a different content file for net35 than for winrt45.

Thanks,
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet team are planning to add support for this in NuGet 2.0. There is a [discussion on the NuGet forum](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/354463) about how this support would work.

The only way to do this with the current version of NuGet is to create a PowerShell install.ps1 script to copy the appropriate content files.

Answer (score 0):

This was implemented in NuGet 2.0: "Starting in NuGet 2.0, in addition to assembly references, content files as well as PowerShell scripts can be grouped by target frameworks too." See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package.